# Сделать запрос initLoader

Tags: android

Здраствуйте , я использую `Cursoradapter`

и в `onCreateView` делаю следущий запрос

`getActivity().getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);`

initLoader

```
 @Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    // the uri - places table in the provider
    Uri uri = myData.DB.CONTENT_URI;
    // all columns
    String[] projection = null;
    // all data
    String selection = null;
    // sort by name
    String sortOrder = myData.DB._ID + " asc" ;

    // create the loader:
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri, projection, selection, null, sortOrder);

}
```

как мне сделать этотже запрос в другом месте кода и с новыми параметрами ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для повторного запуска уже созданного `CursorLoader` используется метод [`restartLoader()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html#restartLoader(int,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks%3CD%3E))

```
getActivity().getLoaderManager().restartLoader(1, null, this);
```

Если вам нужно изменять параметры при инициализации\перезапуске `Loader`, передавайте их через `Bundle` вторым аргументом запроса (который у вас в данном коде `null`. Метод `onCreateLoader()` получает этот `Bundle` вторым аргументом.

Comment: спосиба , подскажите как правильно задать selection в методе onCreateLoader при запросе ?

Comment: спосиба ))))))))))))))))